# SPARK collect side-effects not well understood

Tags: apache-spark

In the continual quest for knowledge and the enlightenment of others, I note that
the below rdd3 statement works without collect but it does not with collect. I am wondering why as if you may get quite confused when reading what collect does. The examples are contrived so don't worry about that.

NP:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((" aaa", "x"), ("bbbb ", "y"), (" cc ", "z"), ("gggg  ", " a"), ("    ", "b")))
val rdd2 = rdd.map{ case (field1, field2) => ( field1.replaceAll(" ", ""), field1.trim, field1, field2) }.collect
val rdd3 = rdd2.map{ case (field1, field2, field3, field4) => (field1.replaceAll(" ", ""), if (field1.trim == "") " "  else field1 , field3, field4) }
```

Problem:

```
val rdd3 = rdd2.map{ case (field1, field2, field3, field4) => (field1.replaceAll(" ", ""), if (field1.trim == "") " "  else field1 , field3, field4) }.collect
```

Returns:

```
notebook:7: error: missing argument list for method collect in trait TraversableLike
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `collect _` or `collect(_)(_)` instead of `collect`.
val rdd3 = rdd2.map{ case (field1, field2, field3, field4) => (field1.replaceAll(" ", ""), if (field1.trim == "") " "  else field1 , field3, field4) }.collect
```

Hard to follow for the novice. How would I get around this looking at the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collect() method returns the output of an entire rdd/dataset as an array to the driver machine.

So in your example rdd2 returns an array to the driver machine, so you cannot use it like an RDD. Please remove collect method while creating rdd2 then your third statement of collect should work.

Comment: yes, I realize that, but the reasoning as to why is what I am asking. there are many other statements that work fine, e.g. the rdd2 statement, so question not answered

Comment: Rdd2 will work as you are performing map operation on an RDD itself. basically while you are doing collect() and assigning to rdd2 variable it’s not a type as RDD, please check its data type and it will be of array of string not RDD OF STRING. So if you are going to use any map, flat map or any spark api on top of rdd2 variable it won’t work. But if you want to convert to string then you can use mkstring. Please let me know for any issues

Comment: I find the collect explanation not well explained but now indeed yes subtle

Comment: Collect is a method where it will get all the data of rdd from different data nodes to your driver machine as an array. So basically it is used if you want collate your result into one machine. Though it’s not advisable to use collect on huge dataset as there is chance of out of memory error of driver.

Comment: It was an oversight, but a useful one in a strange way